# How to cover map<id,Id> in test class

Tags: apex

Please let me know how to cover the Map in test class.

```
Map<Id,Id> mapIdString = new Map<Id,Id>();
for(sObject sObj: ObjList){
    Id sLastMod = (Id)sObj.get(Label.LastModifiedById);
    mapIdString.put(sObj.Id,sLastMod);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of testing maps, you shouldn't have to do anything special, you just need to make sure that your data is set up to populate the maps appropriately.

- If value is not null for  "ObjList". Then automatically map
  will cover in your case
- You have to cross verify "ObjList" value